# How to navigate to different screen with quick actions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a simple coupon application, but I'm struggling with quick actions package.

What I am trying to do is to allow user to navigate to a screen using quick action. I created one quick action and tried to navigate to it, but it doesn't work.

When I click on my quick action, it redirects me to my home screen of my application. This is not what i want.

[image: Quick action]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './route_generator/route_generator.dart';
import 'package:quick_actions/quick_actions.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final QuickActions quickActions = QuickActions();
    quickActions.initialize((shortcutType) {
      if (shortcutType == 'cheeseburger') {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/generatedMailCouponScreen', arguments: 'assets/images/without_logo_coupon_cheeseburger.png');
      }
    });

    quickActions.setShortcutItems([
      ShortcutItem(
        type: 'cheeseburger', localizedTitle: 'Cheeseburger'
      )
    ]);

    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      theme: _theme()
    );
  }
}



ThemeData _theme() {
  const LargeTextSize = 26.0;
  const MediumTextSize = 20.0;
  const Body1TextSize = 16.0;
  const Body2TextSize = 12.0;

  const String FontNameDefault = 'Lato';

  return ThemeData(
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder()
      }
    ),
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.blueGrey[700],
      textTheme: TextTheme(
        title: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
          fontSize: LargeTextSize
        )
      )
    ),
    tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: Body1TextSize,
      ),
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: Body1TextSize
      )
    ),
    indicatorColor: Colors.blueGrey[100],
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[600],
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      title: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: LargeTextSize,
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      body1: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: Body1TextSize,
        color: Colors.white
      ),
      body2: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
        fontSize: Body2TextSize,
        color: Colors.white
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a global navigator key.
First setup a global navigator key like this:

```
...
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  ...
```

and add the navigatorKey to the MaterialApp:

```
...
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
  navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
  theme: _theme()
);
...
```

After setting this up you can navigate between your screens using the navigator key like this:

```
App.navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed("/"); // to navigate to the home page
App.navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed("/details/1"); // to navigate to a detail page
```